# Chef - template inside a provider not finding source

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a little resource and provider for nginx sites which writes out a config file for a site.

```
action :start do
    template "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my_site" do
        source    "nginx_site.conf.erb"
        notifies  :reload, "service[nginx]"
    end
end
```

When I use it from another cookbook the template nginx_site.conf.erb is not found as chef is looking for a template where this resource is called from.

Is there a way to tell chef to look for a template inside the nginx resource & provider cookbook?

Comment: I would really be interested in seeing an answer to this question. But if there isn't one, I would suggest you define the template (with action :nothing) outside of the specific resource and just notify it upon action, as you do in the template resource. If the start action isn't called, the template resource won't either. So you will have the same results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set *cookbook* value for [*template*](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_template.html).

```
action :start do
  template "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my_site" do
    source    "nginx_site.conf.erb"
    notifies  :reload, "service[nginx]"
    cookbook 'nginx'
  end
end
```