# Chef looking in wrong folder for template

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, supervisord

Here's my setup

```
cookbooks /
    supervisord /
        definitions /
            supervisord_group.erb
        templates /
            process_group.conf.erb
    my_app /
        recipes /
            default.rb
```

In `cookbooks/supervisord/definitions/supervisord_group.erb` I have this:

```
define :supervisord_group, :programs => [], :enable => true do
include_recipe "supervisord::install"

if params[:enable]
    template "#{node[:supervisord][:conf_dir]}/#{params[:name]}_group.conf" do
    source "process_group.conf.erb"
            variables({
        :name => params[:name],
        :programs => params[:programs].join(",")
    })
    owner node[:user]
    group node[:group]
        mode 0755
    end
end
end
```

In cookbooks/my_app/recipes/default.rb I have this:

```
supervisord_group "myapps" do
    programs ["test1", "test2"]
end
```

The problem is that when I run it I get an error that it's unable to find the template `process_group.erb.conf`. Here's the output:

```
Cookbook 'my_app' (0.0.0) does not contain a file at any of these locations:
templates/ubuntu-10.04/process_group.conf.erb
templates/ubuntu/process_group.conf.erb
templates/default/process_group.conf.erb
```

If my `supervisord_group` definition is the one referencing the template why is it expecting the `my_app` cookbook to have it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

So it looks like there is a not-so-clearly-documented property of the template provider that allows you to specify the cookbook that the template lives in. You have to add `cookbook "supervisord"` to the template setup for it to find it properly.

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659638/chef-template-inside-a-provider-not-finding-source)

Comment: It's actually very well documented [here](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_template.html). Look in the Attributes section, it's the second one on the list.